# This Code gives me this error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] the system can not find the route

Tags: python

```
import os
import glob

# Get the list of PDF files in the folder
folder = r"Files to remane folder"
pdf_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "*.pdf"))

# List of months of the year
months = ["October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July/August", "September"]

# Iterate over each PDF file and rename it
for i, pdf_file in enumerate(pdf_files):
    # Get the base name of the file without the extension
    base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_file))[0]

    # Get the corresponding month
    month = months[i % len(months)]

    # Create the new file name with the added month in uppercase
    new_name = f"{base_name} - {month}.pdf"

    # Rename the file
    new_path = os.path.join(folder, new_name)
    os.rename(pdf_file, new_path)

    print(f"File renamed: {pdf_file} -> {new_name}")
```

this code should take the names of the PDFs in a folder, then add the months on the list at the end, it worked fine until i put July/August in the list.

Comment: What filename do you expect for the month `"July/August"`? `/` is a directory separator in Linux, and it's just not allowed in filenames on Windows.

Comment: Next time, please extract a [mcve] first. You would have found that error yourself.